# PHP Creating an Authorisation Header

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to create a Authorisation header in PHP, Every attempt i have tried results in bad request, I dont know if its my method or formatting.

The Document i have from the API is the header needs to be in the following format:

```
POST https://api.URL.com/api/access/authtoken/ 
HEADERS { 
"Accept": "application/json", 
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
, 
"Authorization": "Basic 8fqchs8hsafhjhc8392ch8evhdv 
dvf4239gy0wNVSDVHSDJVJWd209qfhznznc932fyzIHFEOIGH
CNFCaFWFh83hfwehvljv9fbueqgf89ahwaoihOHOIHBVjeh890
owev98ewgvw209fyqnf0fmf9fm0snfa098nfw0q09fmevm9eqZ
HF89FHWE==" 
} 
DATA: { 
"grant_type": "password", 
"username": "APIUSERNAME", 
"password": "password" 
}
```

The latest attempt in PHP i have been using **stream_context_create** and **file_get_contents**

The snippet of code is in the following format.

```
$api_url = 'https://api.URL.com/api/access/authtoken/';

$AuthHeader = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'HEADERS'=>"Accept: application/json" .
               "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
               "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$ClientID:$ClientSecret")),
   'content'=>array(
   'DATA'=>"grant_type:password".
           "username:USERNAME".
           "password:PASSWORD"  )  

);



$context = stream_context_create($AuthHeader);
$result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);
```

Is the way i am creating the header the wrong way or badly formatted. 
The API document is not the best and the response i get gives me no indication to where its failing. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [HTTP stream context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), it's `header`, not `HEADERS`. It also accepts array, for easier multi-header specification.

Content seems to be expected as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you need to encode it with [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query)

Combining that:

```
$api_url = 'https://api.URL.com/api/access/authtoken/';

$AuthHeader = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => array(
      "Accept: application/json",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$ClientID:$ClientSecret")
    ),
    'content' => http_build_query(array(
      "grant_type" => "password",
      "username" => "USERNAME", // to be replaced with actual username value
      "password" => "PASSWORD" // ditto
    ))
  ) 
);

$context = stream_context_create($AuthHeader);
$result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked like a charm, I originally used header, but i changed it to headers on the off chance, it was the http_build_query i was missing. You are a star. Thanks again :)

Comment: «*it was the http_build_query i was missing*» — also for string form of header declaration you needed to separate them with CR/LF's (not needed when you pass headers as array). Otherwise they were all used as a single header.